# Update image of NSTextAttachment once already rendered

Tags: uiimage, uitextview, nstextattachment

I have an NSTextAttachment which I want to show a loading image until the image has downloaded and then once it has I want to update the image.

I have all of the logic in place, except when I call `textAttachment.image = image` the second time nothing happens.

How can I update the `NSTextAttachment` once it has already been rendered by the `UITextView`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must always update the user interface from the main thread, not from the socket thread.

Here is a Swift example:

```
// Update UI from main thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  textAttachment.image = image
})
```